# Autolayout of UILabel failing when no single line touches left edge

Tags: ios, ios7, uilabel, autolayout, textkit

I have an NSAttributedString in a UILabel that looks like this:

```
|   Indented line            |
```

Where the |'s mark the UILabel max preferred width. The indented line has been indented using a paragraph style attribute:

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
style.firstLineHeadIndent = 10;
style.headIndent = 10:
```

The result is that the entire text becomes incredibly narrow. Something like this:

```
|   Inde|
|   ted | 
|   Line|
```

There are two ways that I can "fix" this:

1. If I remove the paragraph style then it works (without the indent).
2. If I have a line somewhere that doesn't have a paragraph style

==>

```
|TITLE LINE                  |
|   Indented line            |
```

Neither of these is a viable solution for me. It's hard to understand what's happening, but clearly autolayout feels that it can't determine a layout's width under these circumstance.

Has anyone else seen this? Is there a solution?